# Email has already been taken on login page in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm getting `Email has already been taken`  error  even on login page. Earlier this message was not displayed now I don't know why its checking :uniqueness of email on login.

I have even tried commenting `validates_uniqueness_of :email` or specify it on login(`validates_uniqueness_of :email, :on => :create`) but nothing seems to be working.

I'm using devise gem.

Here is my login page:

```
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name) , :validate=>true) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :email %>

    <%= f.email_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <p>
        <%= f.password_field :password   %>
    </p>
    <div id="lower">
        <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me ,:class=>"check" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Login",:value=>"Login"  %>
        <div>
            <%= link_to "Forgot your password?",new_password_path('registered_user') %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_registered_user_registration_path %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

SessionController

```
  def create
    respond_to do |format|

      format.html{ super }
      format.json do
       .................
      end
      format.js do
         ................. 
      end
    end

  end
```

My route

```
  devise_for :registered_users, :path_names=> {:sign_up=> "signup",:sign_in=> "login", :sign_out=> "logout"}, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations",:sessions=>"sessions" }
```

My model :

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :email,:phone, :address1,:first_name, :last_name,:city , :state, :zip_code

     validates :email, :email_format => true
      validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
      validates_presence_of :current_password, :on => :edit
      validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 6, :on => :create
```

I have found a quick and dirty way  :)  add inline validation in this way :

```
    <%= f.email_field :email , :validate => { :uniqueness => false },:type=>"text" %>
```

Please let me know when you guys get what is the issue.

Comment: can you post your `sessions_controller`?

Comment: @TheChamp I have updated the question. BTW it has nothing to do with sessions_controller its a validation issue. Where its sending a get request to validate email uniqueness on login page.

Comment: PLease post your session controller create method. `Validation` just does not happen. It needs to be triggered. So please post it. And also User.rb (may provide some clarity for anyone who reads the question). Thanks.

Comment: can you post the params and verify which route / action is hit as well ? Might as well be a routing problem.

Comment: why do you explicitly specify controllers ? Do you have other devise-enabled resources ?

Comment: @m_x I had to customize the registration process and their views

Comment: so are you sure it hits the right route / action ?

Comment: @m_x Yeah  every things works perfectly except this validation issue.